# VMware VIX 1.13 on Ubuntu 12.04 not working

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and VMware VIX 1.13 (http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/)

I'm had VMware VIX running on a machine and connecting just fine to our ESXi server, but we migrated machines and now I can't get it to work again.

Here's what I get when I try to run it in terminal (IP and PWD removed)

```
root@dev:/lib# vmrun -T esx -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 -u root -p PASSWORD list
SSLLoadSharedLibraries: Failed to load OpenSSL libraries. libdir is /usr/lib/vmware

VMware Workstation Error:
VMware Workstation unrecoverable error: (vthread-3)
SSLLoadSharedLibraries: Failed to load OpenSSL libraries. libdir is /usr/lib/vmware
You can request support.

To collect data to submit to VMware support, choose "Collect Support Data" from the Help menu.
You can also run the "vm-support" script in the Workstation folder directly.
We will respond on the basis of your support entitlement.
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT -- I fixed it**
Simple mistake here, I didn't notice it until now. Last week I upgraded to VMware VIX 1.13; I just downgraded back to 1.12 and it's fixed.

tl;dr VMware VIX 1.13 is **not compatible** with ESXi 5.1; you must use 1.12.

Comment: When you can, please make sure to write that up as an answer and then mark it as accepted so in case others go searching they'll notice your Q and the corresponding A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake here, I didn't notice it until now. Last week I upgraded to VMware VIX 1.13; I just downgraded back to 1.12 and it's fixed.

tl;dr VMware VIX 1.13 is **not compatible** with ESXi 5.1; you must use 1.12.